# Write XML-Code with XMLWriter

Tags: php, xml

Good Morning Community,

exist in the php framework or especially in the XMLWriter class a method to write pure XML code?

My aim is it to embed XML Data from the DB to other XML code created with the XMLWriter class.

E.g. i have written

```
<Data>
  <Element1 attribute="Value">


    <!-- 
         Write here XML code from DB,
         so following code retrieved from DB as text
    -->

    <strong>Bolded</strong> text and <em>italic</em> text....

  </Element1>
</Data>
```

i know that the functions writeElement, startElement and endElement exists, but that solve not my problem.

So the source have to look something like that:

```
// $sourceFromDB is a string as XML code got from the DB

$writer->startElement("Data");

$writer->startElement("Element1");
$writer->writeAttribute("attrbitue", "Value");

// The code to write XML code
// writeXML is a pseudo method
$writer->writeXML($sourceFromDB);

$writer->endElement();
$writer->endElement();
```

or must i write an algorithm to do this?

Anyone an idea?
Thanks a lot.

Kind regards
sb

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
writeRaw($content) writes XML code to the stream.

Comment: I read this question yesterday but I just couldn't figure out what you meant. Glad you got it.